Relative degree of a transfer function
Consider the (scalar) transfer function
$$T(s)=\frac{p_ms^m+p_{m-1}s^{m-1}+\cdots+p_1s+p_0}{s^n+q_{n-1}s^{n-1}+\cdots+q_1s+q_0},$$
with $p_m\neq0$ and $m<n.$ The coefficients $p_i$ and $q_i$ are real (and $m$ denotes the degree of the numerator polynomial rather than the number of inputs). The relative degree $r$ of a transfer function is defined as the integer $r=n-m.$
Let $( A, B, C, 0)$ be a realization of $T(s)$ with the matrix pair $(A,B)$ controllable. Show that
$T(s)$ has relative degree $r$ if and only if
$$CA^{i-1}B=0\text{ for all }i\in(1,2,\ldots,r-1)\text{ and }CA^{r-1}B\neq0$$

What is a realization of $T$?

What have you tried to show this?

It means that $T(s) = C (sI -A)^{-1}B$.

It is straightforward to see that for non trivial $T(s) \in \mathbb{R}(s)$ that the relative degree $r$ is given by $\max \{ r \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \lim_{s \to \infty} s^r\,T(s) \text{ is finite}\}$.
Suppose $(A,b,c,0)$ is any realisation of the (strictly proper) $T(s)$, then
$T(s) = c (sI-A)^{-1} b$ and it is straightforward to see that
for $|s| > \rho (A)$ (spectral radius) that
$T(s) = {1 \over s} (cb + {1 \over s} cAb + {1 \over s^2} cA^2b + \cdots ) $.
Hence $T(s)$ has relative degree $r$ iff $r$ is the smallest natural number such that $cA^{r-1} b$ is non zero.
The fact that $(A,b)$ is or is not cc. is irrelevant.

The definition of relative degree does not look correct. If $T(s)$ is strictly proper we can pick $r=0$. Yet this is not the relative degree. Also, perhaps it would be better to avoid the use of the word "straightforward" as it is subjective. Instead, explain why this is the case.

If T is strictly proper then r is at least one. That is straightforward to see

Sorry. Missed the max operator. But you should still avoid such words as they do not provide any explanation.

I will use obvious instead.

In my answer I will only consider single-input-single-output (SISO) systems, since the mentioned transfer function in your questions is also SISO. For a SISO state space model $(A,B,C,D)$
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= A\,x + B\,u, \\
y &= C\,x + D\,u,
\end{align}
\right. \tag{1}
\label{eq:ss}
$$
with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $u\in\mathbb{R}$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times 1}$, it is not that straight forward in general to calculate the relative degree directly. One thing that can quickly be determined from a state space model is whether it has relative of exactly zero, so when the order of the numerator matches with order of the denominator, sometimes also called biproper, which is the case when $D\neq0$.
By multiplying the numerator repeatedly by $s$, which is equivalent to differentiating the output of the state space model, and checking when the relative degree of the new system is zero also allows one to determine the relative degree. I will expand on showing that $D\neq0$ implies a relative degree of zero in the section below and in the section after that I will explain the multiplying by $s$ to arrive at a way of calculating the relative degree of a state space model and in the last section I will give a short example.

To show that a state space model has a relative degree of exactly zero when $D\neq0$ can be derived from mapping of the state space model to the corresponding transfer function
$$
G(s) = C\,(s\,I-A)^{-1} B + D. \tag{2}
\label{eq:ss2tf}
$$
The matrix inverse can also be written using the adjugate and determinant
$$
(s\,I-A)^{-1} = \frac{\text{adj}(s\,I-A)}{\det(s\,I-A)},
$$
with $\det(s\,I-A)$ a scalar containing a polynomial in $s$ of degree $n$ and $\text{adj}(s\,I-A)$ a matrix of size $n\times n$, with each element containing a polynomial in $s$ of degree of at most $n-1$, because adjugate matrix is constructed by calculating the determinant of the submatrices of $s\,I-A$ from which a specific row and column are omitted (hence the at most $n-1$). Substituting this into \eqref{eq:ss2tf} and bringing everything under the same denominator gives
$$
G(s) = \frac{C\,\text{adj}(s\,I-A)\,B + \det(s\,I-A)\,D}{\det(s\,I-A)}, \tag{3}
\label{eq:ss2tf2}
$$
where the term $C\,\text{adj}(s\,I-A)\,B$ in numerator is a summation of polynomials in $s$ of degree of at most $n-1$, which at most can also only be a polynomial in $s$ of degree of at most $n-1$, while the term $\det(s\,I-A)\,D$ in numerator is a polynomial in $s$ of degree $n$ when $D\neq0$. The denominator is $\det(s\,I-A)$, so a polynomial in $s$ of degree $n$. Thus the order of the numerator and denominator are both equal to $n$ when $D\neq0$, and thus in that case the relative degree would be zero.

Multiplying the numerator of a transfer function by $s^k$ raises the order of the numerator by $k$
$$
T(s)=\frac{s^k\,(p_ms^m+p_{m-1}s^{m-1}+\cdots+p_1s+p_0)}{s^n+q_{n-1}s^{n-1}+\cdots+q_1s+q_0}
=\frac{p_ms^{m+k}+p_{m-1}s^{m+k-1}+\cdots+p_1s^{1+k}+p_0s^k}{s^n+q_{n-1}s^{n-1}+\cdots+q_1s+q_0},
$$
and thus reduces the relative degree with $k$ ($r=n-m-k$). The equivalent operation, of multiplying the numerator by $s^k$, for a state space model is to differentiate the output of the system $k$ times with respect to time.
As discussed in the previous section, one can easily check when a state space model has a relative degree of zero, when the direct feedthrough term $D$ from the input $u$ to the output $y$ is non-zero. Combining this enables one to calculate the relative degree from a state space model by repeatedly differentiating the output until at a $k$th derivative the direct feedthrough term from input to output is non-zero. The relative degree of the original, not differentiated, system is then determined to be equal to $k$.
The first and second time derivative of the output $y$ from \eqref{eq:ss} are give by
$$
\frac{d\,y}{dt} = C\,(A\,x+B\,u) + D\,\frac{d\,u}{dt} = C\,A\,x + C\,B\,u + D\,\frac{d\,u}{dt},
$$
$$
\frac{d^2\,y}{dt^2} = C\,A\,(A\,x+B\,u) + C\,B\,\frac{d\,u}{dt} + D\,\frac{d^2\,u}{dt^2} = C\,A^2\,x + C\,A\,B\,u + C\,B\,\frac{d\,u}{dt} + D\,\frac{d^2\,u}{dt^2}.
$$
When all the time derivatives of the output up to order $k-1$ do not contain a non-zero direct feedthrough term means that $D=0$ and $C\,A^i B = 0\ \forall\ i=0,1,\dots,k-2$ and one needs to keep on differentiating the output in order to identify the relative degree. When no non-zero direct feedthrough term has been encountered, the expression for the $k$th time derivative of output $y$ from \eqref{eq:ss} can be generalized to the following simplified form by omitting all terms that are zero
$$
\frac{d^k\,y}{dt^k} = C\,A^k x + C\,A^{k-1} B\,u. \tag{4}
$$
So when $D=0$ and $C\,A^i B = 0\ \forall\ i=0,1,\dots,r-2$ and $C\,A^{r-1} B\neq0$ means that the $r$th time derivative of the output does have a non-zero direct feedthrough term and it can be concluded that the relative degree of \eqref{eq:ss} is equal to $r$.

For example consider the following state space model
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\,x + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}\,u, \\
y &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\,x,
\end{align}
\right. \tag{5}
$$
$D=0$ so $r>0$; $C\,B = 0$ so $r>1$; and $C\,A\,B = 2$ so $r=2$ is the relative degree.
This can also be confirmed by calculating the equivalent transfer function corresponding to the state space model
$$
G(s) = \frac{2\,s + 1}{s^3 + s^2 + 2\,s + 1},
$$
which indeed has a relative degree of 2.
